# CodeIgniter adding a subfolder as a link on the menu

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, codeigniter

I am an admin to a website that was created using the codeigniter framework. I have a sub-folder in the public-html which is a separate website on its own(html) lets call it digital. I would like to display the website as a menu item, so that when someone clicks on that menu labelled 'digital' it opens up the website.

So far I have managed to copy the index file to the applications/controllers and applications/views files but the page is displaying with just the content without the js, images and css files. How do I ensure that the css, images and js files are captured? Or where should I place these files?

Comment: please provide some code, when you are adding link of another website then using <?=base_url()?>...you can access all files , images etc

Comment: check if you get public urls from digital, if yes then use them directly. ex: `http://localhost/digital/<page name>`

Comment: Here is code for the index file which was initially a html which i changed to .php and renamed the index file to digital.php because there is already the existing index file for the main website

Comment: <html>
 <head>
  <title>DIGITAL</title>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

Comment: <script src="js/init.js"></script>
  <noscript>  
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css')?>" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/skel.css')?>" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style-wide.css')?>" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style-normal.css')?>" />
  </noscript>

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.
If your stylesheet is in css folder and named style.css, base_url() returns site base url.
Please place your css, js files under css and js folder or create if folders does not exists under public_html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/style.css')?>" />
```

Comment: I have tried the above code and the page goes blank. I have copied the css, js and images folder to public html but its still blank. I dont know if I am not getting how the base_url works but what am wondering is the main website is already using the base url for its js and css files. How is this also working for a subfolder?